# Echo Javascript File in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, echo

I am trying to echo out a .js file within a head tag with php.  The css file is working properly, however the js file isn't getting included.  Here is what I have:

```
echo '<head>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="systemframe.css"/>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="mainmenu.js"></script>';
echo '</head>';
echo '<form>';
echo '<body>';
...
echo '</body>';
echo '</form>';
```

I verified that the js file is good by manually placing it in the head tag of the index.html file.  The js file is located in the same folder as all of the other files, so there are no file directory levels.  My goal is to dynamically add js files to the head of the website through php.  I saw other similar examples, so I am a bit confused why it is not working.

Comment: If you press F12 in your web browser (developers tools) and then go to resources, does it say the file is included? Also, if you go to console are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: `<form><body></body></form>` ?!? Try to use `<body>` and then `<form>`. I know it's unrelated, but it will definitely fix some bugs down the road...

Comment: Change `type="test/css"` to `type="text/css"`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, the css is fine, however I changed the test to text.  I use Safari's activity window to verify what files are downloaded and the js file doesn't show up?

Comment: @user175328 are you able to see the inclusion in page source ?

Comment: Hi Sahal, from the page source neither file shows up.  However, from the activity window, the css file shows that it was downloaded to the browser.

Comment: For anyone, I guess confirmation that this way usually works would be great, at this point.  I tried adding a blank js file and that did not show up either.  Also, for testing purposes, I echoed a second css file, in place of the js file.  The browser instead downloaded the second css file, but not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
echo '<head>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="systemframe.css"/>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="mainmenu.js"></script>';
echo '</head>';

echo '<body>';
echo '<form>'; <------
...
echo '</form>';<------
echo '</body>';
```

Your form tag should come inside the body tag, not outside.

Check whether you have JS error on your console(Developer tools). Make sure that JS is attached correctly.

One last thing `type="test/css"` should be `type="text/css"` in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="systemframe.css"/>
                               ^------------------- should be text
```

Comment: What is the difference in answer and above question ?

Comment: Hi Dasun, I changed test to text and moved the form tags in between the body tags.  I still cannot get the js file, however the css file is fine?

Comment: where is `test` in his css link ?

Comment: Check whether you have JS error on your console(Developer tools). Make sure that JS is attached correctly.

Comment: @Sahal read the full sentence. I edited anyway so that it helps

Comment: also, use self closing script tag<script src="xxx" type="text/javascript" />